# or command in if statement not working properly

Tags: python

In the code below, the if statement is triggering no matter the condition satisfies or not.
the problem is with 'or'  or anything else i do not know. please help

```
while True:
q = input("WRITE:")
if 'a' or 'b' in q:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

I saw some fix about it like applying parenthesis i.e

```
while True:
q = input("WRITE:")
if('a') or ('b') in q:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

but this is also triggering no matter the condition satisfies or not.

I also tried this

```
while True:
q = input("WRITE:")
if('a' or 'b') in q:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

but this also did not work please help me. how to fix it

Comment: This is parsed the same as `if ('a') or ('b' in q)`; `in` does not "distribute" over `'a' or 'b'`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use it like this:

```
if 'a' in q or 'b' in q:
    ...
```

It is necessary to check for every variable if it is in `q`.

Clause under `if`:

```
if 'a':
```

will always be executed, because it is "truthy". Python considers string "truthy" if it is not an empty string.

"falsy" are empty strings, 0 integer, empty arrays and empty dicts.

Comment: There's also `if any(x in q for x in ['a', 'b']):`, but that's overkill for just two options.

Comment: @chepner literally I was going to paste `if any( x in ['a', 'b'] for x in q):` as answer and I saw your comment, that stopped me.