# Issue with Conditional in Print Statement in Python

Tags: python

When I try to print a conditional in Python, it doesn't return the actual result but the first string in the print statement.

```
letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

print('a' or 'b' in letters)
```

This should print "True", but it instead prints

```
a
```

Why does this happen, and do you have anything to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Common misunderstanding in python.  Python parses that as `'a' or ('b' in letters)` and since `or` evaluates to the first truthy thing it sees, it returns 'a'.  You want ` 'a' in letters or 'b' in letters`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplest way to check if multiple items are (or are not) in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22673770/simplest-way-to-check-if-multiple-items-are-or-are-not-in-a-list), [or command in if statement not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62286603/4518341)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`or` is not distributed over `in`, so it's being parsed as

```
print('a' or ('b' in letters))
```

Since `'a'` is a truthy value, that's the value of the expression. You need to test each one separately.

```
print('a' in letters or 'b' in letters)
```

If you have a list of strings you want to check, you can use `any()`

```
test = ['a', 'b']
print(any(t in letters for t in test))
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the precedence of operators: `in` comes before `or`, so what you have is the same as `'a' or ('b' in letters)`. Then `or` stops at the first value that is `True`, and `bool('a')` is `True`, so you get 'a'.

For what you want, try either:

```
print(bool({'a', 'b'}.intersection(letters)))

# or

print('a' in letters or 'b' in letters)
```

Comment: I think operator precedence is a red herring here. `('a' or 'b') in letters` is also not what OP wants. It'll work in this case, but only because `'a' or 'b'` -> `'a'`. On the other hand, `('z' or 'b') in letters` would fail.